# How to get component object from its name only

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have this code

```
<div>
    <wizard-step
    [component]="'ExampleComponent'"
  ></wizard-step>
</div>
```

ExampleComponent is a component that I want to extract in the component, but when using the component variable, the result is a string in which I want to get the Component object from that name.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: To me it's a bit unclear what you want to achieve

Comment: I want to get ExampleComponent as a component object and not a string

Comment: if you want to add a component template inside another component template use <ng-content> https://angular.io/guide/content-projection

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the component to the child component as an object reference you could retrieve it in the component using https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

```
@ViewChild(ExampleComponent) exampleComponent: ExampleComponent;
```

Then in your template you would pass it like this

```
<div>
  <wizard-step [component]="exampleComponent"></wizard-step>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options came to my mind for your issue. Either you create a helper variable or use `ng-content` as @dmance suggested.

**Option 1 - Helper variable**

You need a helper variable because the HTML doesn't have access to the imports, so you need a "proxy" to access the component

TS

```
exampleComponent: Type<ExampleComponent> = ExampleComponent;
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <wizard-step [component]="exampleComponent"></wizard-step>
</div>
```

**Option 2 - `ng-content`**

The content projection is helpful, for example, as soon as the content changes in each component and you don't want to add a lot of inputs to your component.

HTML

```
<div>
  <wizard-step>
    <example-component></example-component>
  </wizard-step>
</div>
```

But you need to adjust your `wizard.component.html`:

```
<!-- Some HTML -->
...
<div>
  <ng-content></ng-content> 
  <!-- Your component is rendered here => ng-content is the anchor -->
</div>
...
<!-- SOME HTML -->
```

If you use this option you don't need the `@Input` in your Typescript file. For more information see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection).

Comment: The problem is that the client will enter the specified component in which I cannot import or write its type. Is there a method that could work this out?

Comment: So, the component which contains the `wizard-step` also receives the component as input?